# How to clone libgdx world

Tags: java, libgdx

This seems more like a general programming question than a gamedev question so I am asking it here. I need to clone the libgdx world to store the state of all objects as backup at a particular time and later on resume from there. So what I thought was simply,

```
backupWorld = world.clone();
```

However, the World class in libgdx does not implement Cloneable. The class is final so I cannot extend it and I cannot edit the source. What options do I have left? What other solutions could be possible?

Thanks

Comment: I think the only way is to read all the bodies in the world sequentially and save their states. then when you need to make a copy of world re-implement it and add the bodies you saved.